# How to run a CRON every 8h and 1 minute

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

So this is a problem I have encountered: I want to run a certain script every 8 hours and 1 minute. Due to the 24 hour loop of CRONjobs I'm a bit stuck on how to continue this 8h1m interval onto the next day.

I'm using Laravel PHP framework if that might help in finding an answer.

Other solutions besides CRON are welcome too. Note though that I would very much like to handle it serverside with PHP (I know its much easier in JavaScript where you would just interval 8h1m);

Comment: Why the 1 min though?

Comment: it has to do with the other server that i have to send data to. It has a rate limiter of 8 hours, so posting at exactly 8h intervals works buggy. There's no way I can change this. Also, I couldve also asked for "run a cron every 8h and 30 minutes" since that would be similar to solve

Comment: Laravel's task scheduling ... ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling

Comment: that uses CRON as its main trigger

Comment: 30 mins is simpler, as you only have 2 options, 0/30 for minute and then */8 hours? (not sure about the syntax for hours)

Comment: in cron tab the syntax : `Minute   Hour   Day of Month       Month          Day of Week        Command ` you should use something like `1 8 * * * php /path/to/your/script`

Comment: @cmnardi, that's 08:01 every day. It will just run once in a 24 hour period. Something like `1 */8 * * * ...` would be closer, but it would still execute the script 8 hours after the last time (00:01, then 08:01, then 16:01).

Comment: yes but the logic to calculate that onto the next cronjob. The thing is neither of them fit neatly into 24h. Imagine a call at 08:30, 17:00, and 01:30. The solution is to have the next call be at 10:00 (which is +08:30)

Comment: sorry ... this way will run at 0:01, 8:01, 4:01PM:  `1 0,8,16 * * * php /path/to/your/script` more examples : https://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html

Comment: @cmnardi yes which doesnt answer the question. That job has 8h in between. Not 8h and 1m

Comment: Bah, you're right. Another option would be to store "last run" and have the cron run more often but adding a check that the time is at least "8hrs1min" after that. Will be interesting if doing it strictly in cron only is possible though.

Comment: Since the 8 hours and 1 minute is never going to fit in 24 hours intervals something ugly must be done IMHO. I suggest to check every minute how much time has passed since the last time a successful call was made and (in your case) if more than 481 minutes are already passed a new call is done as Jon Stirling suggested.

Comment: I found this http://serverfault.com/questions/307481/how-to-set-cron-job-with-specific-time-interval maybe it is not possible

Comment: @Jon yes im having a look at that at the moment. I think im getting closer to a solution here. My task has a database-row associated with it which also stores the time it was last executed. The laravel scheduler is fired every minute (using CRON * * * * *) and then the registered tasks are fired on their CRON value (so these tasks dont actually have their own CRON-call but are checked with the current time, since the scheduler runs every minute until forever)

Comment: It can't be done with cron. You need another tool.

Comment: @RustyX wrong, i'm working on a solution right now. I think the trick is to run a CRON every minute and handle the interval programmatically in PHP

Comment: @Flame - in that case you might as well do it without CRON altogether :-)

Comment: yes but a neverending loop in PHP is not exactly best practice either ;p However, CRON itself is indeed not sufficient for this particular case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about running this every minute.

```
$seconds = time();
$eightHoursThirtyMinutes = (8*60*60)+(30*60);
$minutes = $seconds - ($seconds % 60);

if($minutes % $eightHoursThirtyMinutes == 0)
{
    // code here
}
```

Comment: yes i like this idea, however I might need a fix for the `== 0` equation, since i'm not sure how precise a CRON-call is when comparing time() every minute. Is there a chance a CRON is called 1s later?

Comment: yeah but thats why im comparing `$minutes`

Comment: I ended up using in Laravel `$schedule->call(function(){})->when(function(){// code above});` which seemed to work nicely. The trick was indeed to have a CRON running every minute and check the time serverside using a last_executed property of my model

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build the execution time line of your script, there are web sites like this http://www.cronmaker.com/ that allow you to have your string

I hope I was helpful

Cron format   **0 0 0/8 1/1 * ? ***

**Dates**

1. Friday, September 2, 2016 4:00 PM
2. Saturday, September 3, 2016 12:00 AM
3. Saturday, September 3, 2016 8:00 AM
4. Saturday, September 3, 2016 4:00 PM
5. Sunday, September 4, 2016 12:00 AM

Comment: This does not answer the question, as the requirement is that each interval is 8 hours and 1 minute - not every eight hour or one minute after each eight hour.